# how to read data from AudioBuffer's mData field in iOS?

Tags: ios, file-io, audio

I have certain data in the AudioBuffer(from the recording). Before I write this buffer to file, I want to do something with the PCM samples. How do I read from the AudioBuffer's mData field like I can read using fread?
Can I use fread in a .mm or .m file?

Answer (score 3):

The `AudioBuffer` struct holds it's data in the memory, not in a file. Therefore `fread` is not relevant.
The `mBuffer` is just a pointer to the beginning of the data, and you can use the other two fields of the struct in order to read the data correctly. From [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004488-CH3-SW9):

```
struct AudioBuffer {
   UInt32 mNumberChannels;
   UInt32 mDataByteSize;
   void   *mData;
};
```

`mDataByteSize` tells you how many bytes the buffer holds (so you won't access memory pass the end of the buffer), and the `mNumberChannels` tells you how to re-order your data, e.g. if the buffer holds two channels, then the data is interlaced, i.e samples 1,3,5,... are from channel 1, and 2,4,6,... from channel 2.

Keep in mind you are also responsible for casting the data to the correct type.

Comment: yes that's right. fread can't be used. I am assigning the address as follows: AudBuf.mBuffers[0].mData = inBuffer->mAudioData; where AudioBfferList AudBuf; and AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer; are the declarations. and then I'm doing short int*ptr = (short int*)AudBuf.mBuffers[0].mData; and then I'm doing *ptr to access the audio samples and then doing ptr++ to access the subsequent samples but in the log I can see the value of *ptr is always 0.

Comment: If you just declare a buffer by `AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer` then nobody fills it with samples; you cannot expect the samples to come from nowhere. For example, you could alloc memory for the buffer, and send it to `AudioUnitRender` to fill it up with samples coming from the hardware.

Comment: the samples are already filled in the buffer. I mentioned that only to convey the data type of the inBuffer :) sorry for the confusion.